# Is there any algorithm generating "all" chrodal graphs of order n?

Tags: conjectures, chordal-graphs

I defined a procedure $\Gamma$ to generate graphs following some rules. The obtained graphs form a class of graphs $\mathcal{G}$. I found out that these graphs are chrodal.
In the other hand, I noticed that every chordal graph of order 3 and 4 can be constrcuted by the procedure $\Gamma$.

I implemented an algorithm that generates all $\mathcal{G}$-graphs with $n$ vertices. But I need *some algorithm* that constructs all the chordal graphs with $n$ vertices in order to make the following conjecture more plausible.

> Let $G$ be a graph. Then $G$ belongs to $\mathcal{G}$ if and only if $G$ is chordal.

I want to show that every graph obtained by such an algorithm can also be obtained by the procedure $\Gamma$.

So, my question is: Does any algorithm generating all chordal graphs exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Generate all graphs, then filter out the chordal ones? I'm not sure if anything more efficient is possible... You might look at the implementation of `RandomChordalGraph` in [sage](https://sagemath.org)

Comment: Why not! It isn't a bad idea. Thank you.

Comment: Now we can use Nauty to do that.